# Simple range class

Tags: php, object-oriented

Although my code doesn't support a lot of data types (only one), it's enough to see the general design, which concerns me the most.

Range interface:

```
<?php

namespace Range;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
interface Range {

    function __construct(string $range);
```

IntRange - implementation of range interface for integer

```
namespace Range;
require_once 'vendor\autoload.php';

class IntRange implements Range{
    private $bounds,
            $rangeType,
            $range;
    public function __construct(string $range) {
        $this->range = $range;
        $this->getType();
        $this->getBounds();
    }
    private function boundsToInt(){
        for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
            $this->bounds[$i] = intval($this->bounds[$i]);
        }
    }
    private function getType(){
        $rangeTypeExtractor = new RangeTypeExtractor($this->range);
        $this->rangeType = $rangeTypeExtractor->rangeType();
    }
    private function getBounds(){
        $boundExtractor = new BoundExtractor($this->range, $this->rangeType);
        $this->bounds = $boundExtractor->extractBound();
    }
    private function getBoundForLooping() : array{
        if($this->rangeType == 'inclusive'){
            $start_bound = $this->bounds[0];
            $end_bound = $this->bounds[1] +1;
        }
        else if($this->rangeType == 'exclusive'){
            $start_bound = $this->bounds[0] + 1;
            $end_bound = $this->bounds[1];
        }
        return [$start_bound, $end_bound];
    }

    public function toArray() : array {
        $arr = array();
        $bounds = $this->getBoundForLooping();
        for($i = $bounds[0]; $i != $bounds[1]; $i++){
            array_push($arr, $i);
        }
        return $arr;
    }
    public function toIterator() {
        return new \ArrayIterator($this->toArray());
    }

}
    function toIterator();
    function toArray();

}
```

`IBoundExtractor` - extracts bounds from string

```
<?php

namespace Range;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
interface IBoundExtractor {
    function extractBound();
}
```

`BoundExtractor` - generic class for extracting bounds, it returns the bound of string type, in form of array

```
<?php

namespace Range;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
class BoundExtractor implements IBoundExtractor {
    private $rangeType;
    private $range;
    public function __construct(string $range, string $rangeType) {
        $this->rangeType = $rangeType;
        $this->isBoundValid($range);
        $this->range = $range;
    }
    public function extractBound() : array {
        switch ( $this->rangeType){
            case 'inclusive':
                return $this->getInclusiveRange();
            case 'exclusive':
                return $this->getExclusiveRange();
        }
    }
    private function isBoundValid(string $range){
        if( substr_count($range, ".") > 3 || substr_count($range, ".") < 2){
            throw new InvalidBoundException();
        }
    }
    private function getInclusiveRange() : array{
        return [
                substr($this->range, 0, strpos($this->range, "...")), // until ...
                substr($this->range, strpos($this->range, "...") + 3, strlen($this->range)) // after ...
                ];
    }
    private function getExclusiveRange() : array {
        return [
                substr($this->range, 0, strpos($this->range, "..")), // until ..
                substr($this->range, strpos($this->range, "..") + 2, strlen($this->range)) // after ..
                ];
    }

}
```

`RangeTypeExtractor` - it's extracting the range type, inclusive or exclusive, not to be confused with the data type (e.g. int, string, date). I don't like the name; it's misleading. If somebody can give recommendations for a better name I will be very grateful. On the other hand, the name isn't that bad. If I need a class to determine the date type of the range, I can call it `DateTypeExtractor` or something similar.

```
<?php
namespace Range;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

class RangeTypeExtractor {
    private $range;
    public function __construct(string $range) {
        $this->range = $range;
    }

    public function rangeType() : string {
        if (strpos($this->range, "...") != FALSE) {
            return "inclusive";
        } else if (strpos($this->range, "..") != FALSE) {
            return "exclusive";
        } else {
            throw new InvalidRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```

`InvalidBound` and `InvalidRange` exceptions

```
<?php

namespace Range;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
class InvalidBoundException extends \Exception{
     public function errorMessage() {
        return "Invalid Bound exception. Check if the ../... is correct";
     }
}

<?php

namespace Range;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
class InvalidRangeException extends \Exception{
    public function errorMessage() {
        return "Invalid Range exception.";
     }
}
```

Comment: It seems that instead of `RangeTypeExtractor`, you pasted `BoundExtractor` twice, by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a very odd choice to define `Range` as an interface instead of as a base class (perhaps abstract).  Your interface strangely does not require any methods or constants outside of a constructor.   This doesn't suggest to me a viable interface, as there are no actions or properties whatsoever inferred by being a class implementing `Range` (which coincidentally could be any concrete class).

Though I am a big believer in being biased towards composition over inheritance, I think you truly have an inheritance situation here with the way you have implemented this.

---

I am also struggling a bit to understand what you are gaining with all this code complexity. Why are you working with your data structure like a string? What value are you gaining in defining your own domain-specific language to handle what seems to be a task as simple as managing two pointers against an iterable data structure?

---

Why create your own exceptions for this small bit of code? [PHP's built-in SPL exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php) should already have types that meet your needs in `OutOfBounds`, `OutOfRange` and similar exceptions.

---

Do you really need to define interfaces for specific-use classes?

---

I would like to also add to the "Avoid Undefined Behavior" thoughts from @janos♦ I think his example of "returning early" from within a method is a good demonstration trying to design away `else` conditions.  Most of the time you can do this, unless both branches of code create specific, alternate side-effects.  This helps minimize the number of code paths you have in your application, making is generally easier to read and easier to test/maintain.

Answer (score 2):

#### API design

The `Range` interface is defined by a constructor that takes a string.
What are the important key features of a range?
I think they are:

- start: the start index
- limit: the end, exclusive index
- step: optional, 1 by default

It doesn't matter that the range was originally written as a string, or in a text file, or in a song.

You could define a `RangeParser` whose important key feature will be a `Range parse(string)` method.

I guess the purpose of `IBoundExtractor` is what I mean by `RangeParser`.
I have to guess,
because this kind of interface declaration without any types doesn't describe itself very well:

> ```
> interface IBoundExtractor {
>     function extractBound();
> }
> ```

I suggest:

```
interface RangeParser {
    function parse(string s): Range;
}
```

And the whole inclusive/exclusive concept just complicates things,
because one can be converted into the other.
I suggest to keep just one, exclusive, as I outlined at the top.

#### Iterator pattern

This implementation violates the iterator pattern:

> ```
> public function toIterator() {
>     return new \ArrayIterator($this->toArray());
> }
> ```

The idea of an iterator is to encapsulate the state of an iteration.
An iterator usually contains two things:

- A *reference* to some underlying *iterable*
- The current position

I would like to emphasize the *reference* there.
It should not store a copy of the content it is iterating over.
In theory, you should be able to have an iterator over an infinite data source, a copy of which would obviously not fit within memory.

The current implementation is not such a lightweight object,
and therefore misleading.

#### Avoid undefined behavior

This method is deeply troubling:

> ```
> private function getBoundForLooping() : array {
>     if($this->rangeType == 'inclusive'){
>         $start_bound = $this->bounds[0];
>         $end_bound = $this->bounds[1] +1;
>     }
>     else if($this->rangeType == 'exclusive'){
>         $start_bound = $this->bounds[0] + 1;
>         $end_bound = $this->bounds[1];
>     }
>     return [$start_bound, $end_bound];
> }
> ```

What if `$this->rangeType` is neither inclusive nor exclusive?
Looking at other parts of the code,
`$this->rangeType` is never validated.
It should have been.

I suggest to avoid pointless local variables.
The branches of the `if` statement could return values directly.
And when we write that way,
the problem of the undefined `$this->rangeType` becomes more obvious and harder to miss, for example:

```
private function getBoundForLooping() : array {
    if ($this->rangeType == 'inclusive') {
        return [$this->bounds[0], $this->bounds[1] + 1];
    }
    if ($this->rangeType == 'exclusive') {
        return [$this->bounds[0] + 1, $this->bounds[1]];
    }
    // ? what now?
}
```

#### Unused method

The private `boundsToInt` method is not used anywhere.
As such it's dead code and should be deleted.